# Python KivyMD MDBottomSheet with extra blank space

Tags: python, python-3.x, kivy, kivymd

I'm building an app at the moment, and I want to implement MDBottomSheet there, but there's one problem: the bottomsheet always has some extra blank space.

Here's what it looks like:

[image]

I'm pretty sure you can see that there's blank space after the "Cancel" button, and I don't know how to fix that.

Here's a bit of my Python code:

```
from kivymd.app import MDApp
from kivymd.uix.bottomsheet import MDListBottomSheet

class MainApp(MDApp):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(**kwargs)
    
    def screen_switch(self, scr_name):
        self.root.manager.current = scr_name
        self.root.toolbar.title = scr_name.capitalize()
        
    def open_bottom_sheet(self):
        bottom_sheet_menu = MDListBottomSheet(radius_from="top", radius=15)

        menu_items = [

            ("About the app", lambda x: self.screen_switch("About the app"), "help"),
            ("Leave a review", lambda x: self.screen_switch("Leave a review"), "email"),
            ("Cancel", lambda x: bottom_sheet_menu.dismiss(), "close")
            
        ]

        for txt, func, icon in menu_items:
            bottom_sheet_menu.add_item(txt, func, icon)

        bottom_sheet_menu.open()
```

Here's a bit of my Kivy code:

```
BoxLayout:
    orientation: "vertical"

    toolbar: toolbar

    MDToolbar:
        id: toolbar
        type: "top"
        title: "Plans"
        right_action_items: [("dots-vertical", lambda y: app.open_bottom_sheet())]
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Did you try to change your MDListBottomSheet's **size_hint_y:None** and **height:'200sp'** [change this value as you want]

Answer (score 2):

I tried this workaround and it worked. Insert the following line before the open statement.

```
bottom_sheet_menu.sheet_list.ids.box_sheet_list.padding = (dp (16), 0, dp (16), 0)
```

Hope it works for you too.